# Python text file append error

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I was presented with making a program that uses a text file to store passwords to not forget them. The text file is below.(Passwords.txt)

```
    'Application1': ['Username1', 'Password1']
    'Application2': ['Username2', 'Password2']
```

So, to this I would like to add a new line which would be:
'Application3': ['Username3','Password3']
However when I run the following code it tells me an error saying str is not callable. (passwordsappend.py)

```
    hp = open("Passwords.txt","a") #open the file

    key = raw_input("Which app: ")
    usr = raw_input("Username: ")
    psw = raw_input("Password: ") #make variables to add



    hp.write('\n\''(key)'\': ''[\''(usr)'\', ' '\''(psw)'\'],') #make it so that it's like the rest of the file

    hp.close() #close the file
```

I was trying to study python codes to learn how to, but I can't see the problem... Can anyone give me advice?

Comment: you look like you could use a good 'ole tutorial on the subject. read through exercise 6, 7, 8, and 9 of [This](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) book. This will give you a little better starting point for classic string handling. you may encounter another format not mentioned there referred to as python string formatting. This is a more powerful formatting method (f-strings and `string.format()`), but the classic method is more standard between languages and is therefore necessary to know.

Answer (score 2):

As said in a different answer the problem is your string handling when writing to the file. I would recommend to use string formatting:

```
hp.write("\n'%s': ['%s', '%s']" % (key, usr, psw))
```

See https://pyformat.info/

Recommended code:

```
# Ask for variables to add
key = raw_input("Which app: ")
usr = raw_input("Username: ")
psw = raw_input("Password: ")

# Open file
with open("Passwords.txt", "a") as hp:
    # Add line with same format as the rest of lines
    hp.write("\n'%s': ['%s', '%s']" % (key, usr, psw))
```

If you use the `with open(...) as ...:` you don't have to call the `close` method, it's called automatically when you exit the `with`'s scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is when you try to write to the file. Change it to

```
hp.write('\n\'' + key + '\': ''[\'' + usr + '\', ' '\'' + psw +'\']')
```